# Dynamically (programatically) add new options to dropkick <select> tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown, jquery-dropkick

I am trying to dynamically add options to select tag in jQuery.
This jQuery code below works fine.

```
select.append("<li>opt4</li>");
```

However, when I hover over options, it doesn't highlight any of options and when I select one option, it doesn't change the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically add options to the select, you should do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = new Dropkick("#dropdown");
    select.add("New Option", 2);
});
```

Here is the [reference documentation](http://dropkickjs.com/api.html#method-add)